# Add hyperlinks to datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, hyperlink

I would like to add hyperlinks dynamically to the cell of a specific column in my datatable. Currently my code is only showing the text.

Here is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = null;
string sSQL = "";
string connString = "Datasourceetc";

sSQL = "SELECT TEST_ID FROM TEST_TABLE";

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sSQL, conn);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

sda.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  row["TEST_ID"] = "<a href='www.google.com'>Google</a>"; //<----I only see the text!
}

GridView1.DataSource = dt;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you see if you do a "View Source" in the browser?

Comment: Why not put a HyperlinkField in your GridView columns section instead?

Comment: @David - for an individual <td> block it is showing:
&lt;a href='www.google.com'&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;

Comment: @pjabbott - how would I do that in this instance if I wanted to change all of the values in my "TEST_ID" column to links to google.com?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? as i'm trying to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this through an asp:BoundField you'll want to set the [HtmlEncode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx) to *false*.